# htaccess Friendly Urls Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I sincerely apologize if this is a duplicate. I've looked at so many threads but none seem to apply specifically to what I'm trying to do.. and for some reason, I just have such a difficult time wrapping my brain around .htaccess rewrite rules!

I purchased a php script and after installing it, I create a new post and it works fine.. except of course, it shows: mydomain.com/post.php?id=7

Want I want is to show the title of the post after the .com/

I know some will advise to use a post id or a date or something, but I'd really prefer it to be written as stated.  So the end result would be: mydomain.com/this-is-my-first-post

I then want to be able to correctly call this page. I assume this would all be done in the index.php page (which calls the post.php page)?

I found the line in index.php that currently calls the post and it looks like this:

```
<a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $theArticle['artId']; ?>"><h1><?php echo $theArticle['title']; ?></h1></a>
```

Is that also what I would need to update?

Thanks for any assistance. I really have tried but I am just not programming minded and struggling mightily!

Comment: This is too broad as it does not only involve rewriting the url, but also preparing the title to be used in the url and retrieving the right information from the database. You should break the problem down, try to solve the different parts and post back here with more specific questions.

Comment: If your script is written to take a numeric ID, you can just give it a string title and expect it to work.

Comment: Sorry about that. Please ignore the php part. I'll figure that out if I get the htaccess stuff going. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit too broad, but if you are willing to compromise, you could change the url to something like:

```
mydomain.com/post/7/the-title-of-post-7
```

And then you would only need a rewrite rule and no changes in the database retrieving code.

In that case the rewrite rule would look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+).*$ /post.php?id=$1
                  ^^^^^ capture the number to be used
```

You would of course also need to rewrite all links to the required format.

Comment: Hi Jeroen,
Thanks.. I did actually get it to work as you suggested. The php stuff aside (sorry that I didn't break the question up), is it not possible to just have the domain.com/title  ? I see sites like upworthy that make that happen.  
Just curious. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @MarcyStephens You could, but you would have to generate a unique slug / url-title for every post and index on that. You would also have to change the sql to get the right posts.

Comment: I went ahead and went with this solution. It's as close as I can get and at least that title's up there now. Thanks, jeroen!